# Error Rebuilding Canvas Module with node-gyp: Cannot open include file 'cairo.h' - Electron Forge Build Issue

Tags: node.js, canvas, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

I am encountering a persistent issue while trying to rebuild the Canvas module using node-gyp in an Electron Forge project. The specific error is "Cannot open include file 'cairo.h'", and despite multiple attempts, I have been unable to resolve the issue. Here's a summary of the steps I've taken:

Verified Dependencies:

Checked and confirmed the presence of required dependencies such as GTK in the specified paths.
Reinstallation Attempts:

Reinstalled Node.js, Yarn, and Electron Forge to ensure a clean environment.
Attempted to reinstall the Canvas module using yarn install and npm install.
Ensured that the necessary build tools, like Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, are correctly installed.
Verified Build Environment:

Confirmed that the build environment is set up correctly with all necessary build tools and dependencies.
Reviewed Stack Overflow and Documentation:

Searched and reviewed relevant Stack Overflow threads and documentation for similar issues, applying suggested solutions where applicable.
Despite these efforts, the error persists, and the module fails to rebuild successfully. Any guidance or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
 yarn start        
yarn run v1.22.21
$ electron-forge start
✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating application                                                                                                                                   
✔ Loading configuration                                                                                                                                  
✖ Preparing native dependencies: 1 / 2                                                                                                                   
  › node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\Photobooth-Server\node_modules\canvas'                                                      
◼ Running generateAssets hook                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                         
› Warning: Missing input files:                                                                                                                          
  C:\GTK\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll                                                                                                                           
  C:\GTK\bin\libintl-8.dll                                                                                                                               
  C:\GTK\bin\libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll                                                                                                                     
  C:\GTK\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll                                                                                                                     
  C:\GTK\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll                                                                                                                        
  C:\GTK\bin\libcairo-2.dll                                                                                                                              
  C:\GTK\bin\zlib1.dll                                                                                                                                   
  C:\GTK\bin\libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll                                                                                                                       
  C:\GTK\bin\libpng14-14.dll                                                                                                                             
  C:\GTK\bin\libpango-1.0-0.dll                                                                                                                          
  C:\GTK\bin\libfontconfig-1.dll                                                                                                                         
  C:\GTK\bin\libgmodule-2.0-0.dll                                                                                                                        
  C:\GTK\bin\libgthread-2.0-0.dll                                                                                                                        
  C:\GTK\bin\libexpat-1.dll                                                                                                                              
  C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll                                                                                                                           
  Backend.cc                                                                                                                                             
  C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\Photobooth-Server\node_modules\canvas\src\backend\Backend.h(3,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No…  
  (compiling source file '../src/backend/Backend.cc')                                                                                                    
  Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1                              
      at ChildProcess.onEx…                                                                                                                              

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\Photobooth-Server\node_modules\canvas'
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\Photobooth-Server\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\module-type\node-gyp\node-gyp.js:118:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I tried reinstalling and manually adding the required modules but still the same issue.